# understanding variables and scope

Tags: php

EDIT*** my question was a bit hard to understand...let me try again.

I'm having a problem understanding variables and *the way they execute their value*.

for example.

if I say

```
$var name= 'mike';
```

then if I test the page nothing will show because nothing on the HTML is requesting the value of mike.

if I did

```
echo $name;
```

then the page would simply show mike.....

that said, if i now do this:

```
$connect2db = mysqli_connect('values here');
if(!$connect2db){
    die("error connecting to the database" . mysqli_error);}

$db_query = mysqli_query($connect2db, "INSERT INTO email_list(email, firstname, lastname)
                VALUES ('$email', '$fname', '$lname')");
```

for inserting these values from a form to the db,
I don't understand how the connection and the commands to the db are being called and put into play because to me

$connect2db equals to "those commands" but nothing is calling it. all $connect2db equals to literally is the instruction to take once its called into play.

where on this chunk of code is the connection being called/put into play? where on this code block is the code being called into action(like the echo above calls $name to be put into action to display its value"???.

I don't see anything on that connect2db variable that calls its action/connection properties to work.

like for example if I was to say

pseudo

```
if(is true){
this.$db_query; 
}
```

this I understand, this to me means that IF something evaluates to true, do the thing in the middle..

with the original first code block, its like the variable is naming and calling itself at the same time.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying, but in this scenario everything should be linear (from top to bottom.)

Comment: You code samples are identical, was there some difference that you were trying to express here?

Comment: i edited my question. should be clearer now.

Comment: God I spent 5 minutes correcting lowercase `i`s, apostrophes and so on and you rewrite it all? :D

Comment: Just for the record, you can't have a space in your variable :

$var name= 'mike';
You should have

$name = 'mike';

Comment: @ Damien. Sorry there lol. trying to refine my question for best help lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to

```
$connect2db = mysqli_connect('values here');
```

you mention:

> $connect2db equals to "those commands" but nothing is calling it. all
>   $connect2db equals to literally is the instruction to take once its
>   called into play.

That is **not true.** `mysqli_connect` is a function, and using that syntax (`functionname(argument)`) actually *calls that function*. What `$connect2db` is used for is to store the return value from that function.

To sum up what goes on on that line:

- a call to an existing function called `mysqli_connect` is made. This
  **executes** the function.
- the return value from that function gets stored in a variable named `$connect2db`

The rules governing this assignment are defined by [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), which in this case specifies that the function call will be evaluated prior to the assignment.

To know what the type of return that is, one must look at the API documentation for this function, and in this case it is an object (which represents the connection to the server).

---

Now it is possible to have a variable contain a function, like what you thought your example meant. The syntax of this - called an anonymous function, would be like so:

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
```

You can see that instead of the format:

> functionname + parenthesis + argument(s) + parenthesis + semicolon

the format is:

> function + parenthesis + argument(s) + parenthesis + open bracket
>   + function definition + close bracket + semicolon

In this case, the variable holds what the function does, the function has not beem executed, and to execute it  you would use the first format:

```
$greet('World');
```

Note that this format is available in PHP 5.3 only, prior to that one needed to use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

---

Relevant links:

- [Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)
- [Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)
- [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
- [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)
- [Operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: so, what you are saying is, that what im misunderstanding is the context in which the variable is being used for? that in this case, the variable is not storing the actual command, that IT IS the function command and that the variable in this case is just storing the return value of said function which in this case is true for connected or false if not??

Comment: @somdow: _almost_, but not quite. In your example, the function command is  the block of text `mysqli_connect('...')`. That gets executed first. The return value from that command then gets **stored** in the variable named `$connectdb`. And the return value is not a boolean, it is an object. The test `if (!$connectdb)` will test whether or not the object is `null`. That object, if not null, can then be used for other function calls later, such as `mysqli_query`.

Comment: ok i think i semi understand but...ok let me put it like this, if i have a car key in the ignition (the variable and its value) the car wont start until the ignition is initiated (echo) . in the case of this "resource" variable/or variable containing a resource which is the connect to db function, what is it that makes it turn the ingnition on? just cause the key is in the ignition (variable declared with the function) i still see no key turning to start vehicle. even with $db_query = mysqli_query($connect2db, "INSERT INTO tbl ( values)
VALUES ('more values')");

Comment: -- the $db_query still just lists its value AS the command...or is this kinda like saying VARIABLE == command ? hence why when u define a var like this, it operates WHILE being declared? or am i still confused?

Comment: @somdow: to know exactly how / when the function executes the query, you need to look at the code within the function. But this is not needed, you can trust the API documentation of the function that it will do what it says it does. Inside the function there will be multiple statements and one of them will query the database and create a result object and eventually return it.

Comment: well the problem im having is not knowing when it executes..but the how. For example, let me ask you this. why is it that in the variable $name ='mike' , the variable has to be called upon (for example via echo) for its value to be given forward/returned for use, whereas in the variable(S) connect2db/queryDb/ etc..they just work when declared?? i thought variables ONLY stored values(of any type), and if in the db scenario, if its storing the value of the connection via the mysqli connect function, then isnt the variable equal to the connection itself. where is the call to the connection made?

Answer (score 1):

`$connect2db` contains a *resource* which describes an active connection. `mysqli_query()` expects a resource as first parameter, because it needs to know which connection it should use to do what it does. The "action" starts mainly because you called the function and told it what values to use for its job.

Comment: i edited my question. should be clearer now. oh and thanks for trying on the first one lol. my brain is a mess.

Comment: but i called the function via a variable...if the variable saays "im equal to the connection" is it that then the variable sorta becomes the connection itself?

Comment: Not really. You can imagine it like a cupboard full drawers, where each drawer contains an open connection and has a unique ID. Once you call `mysqli_connect()` you are given the number of one of the drawers. And if you use something like `mysqli_query()` you need to tell it which drawer to use by giving it the return value you gained from connecting. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'll think its realy hear to understand your Question :)
So I try my best :)

If you would print 'Mike' via $name you have to register the Variable

```
<?php

    $name = 'Mike';
    echo $name;

?>
```

This even works in Classes

```
<?php 

    class Names {

        /* Set the default to Mike */
        var $name = 'Mike';

        /* Get the Name */
        public function getName() {
            echo $this->name;
        }

        /* Override the Name */
        public function setName($name = NULL) {
            if($name != NULL) {
                $this->name = $name;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

For building Connections to Databases I suggest to read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php there are some realy usefull Scripts

Greets